# When I give the function a name and trigger it from the console it works perfectly, but when I add the window.onload = to it it never starts

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

This is my code:

```
window.onload = function ()
{
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser
  var login = document.getElementById("NavLogin");
  if (user) {
    login.innerHTML = "Account";
    login.href = "AccountPage/AccountPage.html";
  } 
  else {
    login.innerHTML = "Login";
    login.href = "AccountPage/LoginPage.html"
  }
}
```

I have tried changing it to the onload of the body, but that didn't help either. I do not understand why it only works if called manually.

Comment: It could be that the document has already loaded, so your new listener never fires.

Answer (score 0):

From your code I can see that you need to wait until `#NavLogin` element is loaded. If this element needs to be present in your page to run the rest of the code, then I would suggest you to use a pulling function like bellow:

```
function waitForElement(selector, cb) {
    var tick = setInterval(function () {
      var target = document.querySelector(selector);

      if (null !== target) {
        clearInterval(tick);
        cb(target);
      }
    }, 200);
  };
```

Then you can call the pulling function and pass your target element as the first parameter:

```
waitForElement("#NavLogin", function(login){
  if (user) {
    login.innerHTML = "Account";
    login.href = "AccountPage/AccountPage.html";
  } 
  else {
    login.innerHTML = "Login";
    login.href = "AccountPage/LoginPage.html"
  }

})
```

If the target element is found, the callback function will be called and the target element will be passed as parameter to the callback function